# e1071: CVE returns linear separation, Hold-out returns large error

Tags: r, svm, e1071

I'm using the Adult dataset that can be found here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult

After taking a sample of the dataset, I use the svm function of e1071 to obtain the accuracy with a linear kernel.

```
adult.df = read.csv("sample_adult.csv")
adult.df$X = NULL
Income = adult.df$Income...50k
summary(svm(formula=factor(Income)~., data=adult.df, type="C-classification", cost=1, kernel="linear", cross = 10))
```

This returns:

```
Number of Classes:  2 

Levels: 
  <=50K  >50K

10-fold cross-validation on training data:

Total Accuracy: 100 
Single Accuracies:
 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

However, I've implemented a holdout method of testing the accuracy (this is rather tailored to the dataset):

```
holdout <- function(data, params) {
  # randomize the dataset
  data <- data[sample(1:nrow(data)), ]
  # we use an 50/50 split. train on 50% of the data, test on the other 50%
  training.set = data[1:(nrow(data)/2),]
  t.income = training.set$Income
      testing.set = data[(nrow(data)/2 + 1):nrow(data),]
      # train a model on the training set
      model = NULL
      if(is.null(params$degree)){
    model = svm(formula=t.income~., data=training.set,
              type=params$type, cost=params$cost, 
              kernel=params$kernel, cross=10)
      } else {
        model = svm(formula=t.income~., data=training.set,
                    type=params$type, cost=params$cost, 
                    kernel=params$kernel, degree = params$degree, cross=10)
  }
  print(summary(model))
  # test each point in the testing set
  wrong = 0
  for(i in 1:nrow(testing.set)){ 
    prediction = predict(model, testing.set[i,])
    if(prediction != training.set[i,length(training.set)]) {
      wrong = wrong + 1
    }
  }
  return(wrong/nrow(testing.set))
}
```

If I run the holdout on the same SVM:

```
>holdout(adult.df,list(type="C-classification", cost=1, kernel="linear"))
...
10-fold cross-validation on training data:

Total Accuracy: 100 
Single Accuracies:
 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 



[1] 0.39
```

As you can see... The holdout and CVE values are entirely different. I think my holdout code is correct, and my implementation of the svm function is the problem. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Oh man... The problem was within the loop in the holdout method.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(testing.set)){ 
    prediction = predict(model, testing.set[i,])
    if(prediction != training.set[i,length(training.set)]) {
      wrong = wrong + 1
    }
  }
```

The prediction was being tested against the TRAINING set's ith value, not the testing set. So, the correct loop is:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(testing.set)){ 
    prediction = predict(model, testing.set[i,])
    if(prediction != testing.set[i,length(testing.set)]) {
      wrong = wrong + 1
    }
  }
```

Seems my proof reading accuracy is much worse than my linear svm's.